# SQL showing in place of web page

Tags: sql, codeigniter, wamp

I've copied a codeigniter website from my old computer to my new one, and copied the database.  When I navigate to the site in my localhost however, I just get SQL printed out

```
db->where($cell_name, $id); $this->db->delete($table_name); if (!is_array($tags)) { $tmp = array(); $tmp[] = $tags; $tags = $tmp; } if (!empty($tags)) { foreach($tags as $tag) { switch(gettype($tag)) { case 'integer': $this->db->set($cell_name, $id); $this->db->set('tag_id', $tag); $this->db->insert($table_name); break; case 'string': $tag = strtolower($tag); $results = $this->db->query('SELECT id FROM tag WHERE tag = \''.$tag.'\' LIMIT 1'); if ($results->num_rows() == 1) { $tag_id = $results->first_row()->id; } else { $this->db->set('tag', $tag); $this->db->set('permalink', url_title($tag, 'dash')); $this->db->insert('tag'); $tag_id = $this->db->insert_id(); } $this->db->set($cell_name, $id); $this->db->set('tag_id', $tag_id); $this->db->insert($table_name); break; } } } } function get_active($type, $id, $return_ids = true) { $ret = array(); switch($type) { case 'media': $table_name = 'media_tag'; $cell_name = 'media_id'; break; case 'post': $table_name = 'post_tag'; $cell_name = 'post_id'; break; } if (!$id) { $results = $this->db->query('SELECT tag.id, tag.tag, tag.permalink FROM '.$table_name.', tag WHERE tag_id = tag.id GROUP BY tag.id ORDER BY tag.tag'); if ($results->num_rows() > 0) { foreach($results->result() as $data) { if ($return_ids) $ret[] = $data->id; else $ret[] = (object) array('id' => $data->id, 'tag' => $data->tag, 'permalink' => $data->permalink); } } } else { $results = $this->db->query('SELECT tag.id, tag.tag, tag.permalink FROM '.$table_name.', tag WHERE '.$cell_name.' = '.$id.' AND tag_id = tag.id ORDER BY tag.tag'); if ($results->num_rows() > 0) { foreach($results->result() as $data) { if ($return_ids) $ret[] = $data->id; else $ret[] = (object) array('id' => $data->id, 'tag' => $data->tag, 'permalink' => $data->permalink); } } } return $ret; } }
```

Does anyone know if there's a simple reason for this - some setting I need to turn on in wamp for example, I'm completely at a loss, the files and database are identical on my old and new computers

Comment: Is your new computer running a web server? Is PHP installed and configured to run in the web server?

Comment: Sorry for not replying.  It was something very simple in the end, I had simply not allowed "short open tags" from the WAMP PHP settings

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had simply not allowed "short open tags" from the WAMP PHP settings